# How can convert this request into doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine

could someone help me to traduce this request in doctrine please

```
SELECT *, (SELECT CONCAT(NOM, ' ', PRENOM) as nn 
           FROM BRHM 
           WHERE NNI = a.`NNI_AFFECTATEUR`) as NOM_PRENOM_AFFECTATEUR
FROM BRHM a 
WHERE DATEDIFF(DATE_FIN_ACCES_SI, NOW())<35     
ORDER BY PERIMETRES
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution

$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('OpfBundle:Entity');
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('b')
                    ->select('b.nni, b.nom, b.prenom, b.nniAffectateur,                                                b.dateDebutAccesSi, b.dateFinAccesSi, b.dateFinFidaa, b.autorisation, b.qualifications, b.perimetres')
                    ->addSelect('CONCAT(b.nom, \' \', b.prenom) as NOM_PRENOM')
                    ->leftJoin('OpfBundle:Entity', 'rr', Expr\Join::WITH, 'b.nniAffectateur=rr.nni')
                    ->where('b.nniAffectateur = rr.nni')
                                ->addSelect('CONCAT(rr.nom, \' \', rr.prenom) as NOM_PRENOM_AFFECTATEUR')
                    ->andWhere('b.nniAffectateur=rr.nni')
                    ->andWhere('DATE_DIFF(b.dateFinAccesSi, CURRENT_DATE())<35')
                    ->orderBy('b.perimetres')
                                ->getQuery();
$perim = $query->getResult();